# Undefined symbols for architecture arm6 - iOS utils - in Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker

I am trying to build a Unity project in XCode, but am receiving the following errors. I've tried  almost every strategy on this website, including:

- making sure we are using ILCP22 instead of mono for backend scripting
- setting code stripping/optimisation to low
- manually trying to comment out any reference to these methods in assembly (led to a crash)
- checking library/mic/camera permissions, adding descriptions

Why is this happening/how can I fix it?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__RequestGalleryAuthorization", referenced from:
      _iOsUtils__RequestGalleryAuthorization_mBD2C5275062BA53610A50A8F4683B25EB81D3A63 in Assembly-CSharp12.o
      _iOsUtils_RequestGalleryAuthorization_mD03BD4D97054CA8632CE86039983138983BFED1A in Assembly-CSharp12.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOsUtils__RequestGalleryAuthorization_mBD2C5275062BA53610A50A8F4683B25EB81D3A63)
  "__HasGalleryAuthorization", referenced from:
      _iOsUtils__HasGalleryAuthorization_m0413DA8F81E74F2A44BE14ED5296A7027BF53C7E in Assembly-CSharp12.o
      _iOsUtils_HasGalleryAuthorization_m0C73D68A61862EB8E899F827B358EBEFF3BD26A9 in Assembly-CSharp12.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOsUtils__HasGalleryAuthorization_m0413DA8F81E74F2A44BE14ED5296A7027BF53C7E)
  "__AddImageToGallery", referenced from:
      _iOsUtils__AddImageToGallery_mE6ABA6C00DF9DA06889B7A428DE1AF2F04589641 in Assembly-CSharp12.o
      _iOsUtils_AddImageToGallery_m469B18281B4F123F31685F555708CC3A27F2DD3B in Assembly-CSharp12.o
     (maybe you meant: _iOsUtils__AddImageToGallery_mE6ABA6C00DF9DA06889B7A428DE1AF2F04589641)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```